# Usage of "kick off"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

What does "kick off" mean in [Don't Shoot](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/51074/51074-h/51074-h.htm) by ROBERT ZACKS:

> Of course the men he'd sent out searching knew Billy Shakespeare had
>   **kicked off**, though they weren't sure whether it was last year or ten
>   years ago. But it was a fine trip on the expense account and after a
>   few weeks of riotous searching in London's gayer areas, they wired that
>   Shakespeare had caught a bad cold, the penicillin had run out and he'd
>   not lasted the night.

It doesn't seem to mean "start" nor "angry" to me, what does it mean then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Kick off* is not an idiom I've ever encountered, but I don't think any native speaker would have any difficulty interpreting it from context as meaning *die*. The intransitive preposition *off* usually signifies a departure of some sort, and *kick* is not only familiar in the idiom *kick the bucket*, it's used frequently for abrupt changes of state: *kick into gear*, *kick up a notch*.

This could be a recent coinage, or even the author's own nonce-construction. The idiom may or may not stick; but this is a fine example of the 'productive' capacity of the ‹verb+intransitive preposition› construction, its availability for new and creative uses.